# Increment comparison truncate

Tags: c, if-statement, increment

Why is this expression:
`int value = 0`
`if(++value == ++value)` true?

Shouldn't that be equal to `if(1 == 2)` ? What is it equal to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c the value of the expression `++value == ++value` is *undefined*. Technically, this is due to `==` not being a *sequencing point.*.

Informally, this means that you don't know the order that evaluation of `++` and `==` will occur.